# Keep single class with Proguard?

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I'm trying to "keep" a single class in when using Proguard but it only works when putting it in a directory and "keeping" the entire directory. When trying to match only a file it won't work.

When File.java is put in `com.example.a.directory` this works:

```
-keep class com.example.a.directory.** { *; }
```

But when putting it directly in `com.example.a` this wont work:

```
-keep class com.example.a.File { *; }
```

Why?

Comment: fyi `-keep` implicitly includes `-keepclassmembers`

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll remove them from the question to make it more clear